# How to do something in every possible order

Tags: algorithm, row, formula

I've got the following question. Suppose I have an array Y of N elements, all positive ints. And I have got the value X (positive int). I want to sum up the values of the array into an array with R elements. And for each element of R applies: R<=X.

I want to get as less elements in R as possible. So I have to see what order of elements N fits the best in the value of X, so that X - value of an element of R is as small as possible. Example given below. So to calculate this I thought it was the easiest approach to just check every possibillity, since it's given that N is at maximum around 70. But what is the best way to approach this?

Example:

```
X = 100
Y:
20, 50, 90, 40, 15, 30, 10
(So N = 7)

R:
90+10 = 100
50+30+20 = 100
40+15 = 55
```

So there are at least 3 rows in the most efficient way.

Comment: Is this [bin packing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bin_packing_problem)?

Comment: Yes it is, I saw. Thank you very much, I couldn't find this "algorithm". Is there a way to find the algorithm you need? Because just googling some "random" tags seems to be senseless.

Comment: Unless you want to become well-read in algorithms, asking other people is probably the only way to go.

Comment: I am going to become it, so thanks for your help, it's a step in my learning process ;)